# modify values of elements of an array in gdb for C++

Tags: c++, arrays, gdb

Just wonder how to modify the values of multiple elements of an array under gdb for C++?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: 1) Modify how? By applying a transformation? By assigning an arbitrary value? By copying values from another array? 
2) Which elements? All? A range? Those whose value satisfy a given predicate?

Comment: 1) By assigning an arbitrary value 2) All
But I also like to know what to do for all the others you mentioned.
Tried to find the answers in the gdb manual "Debugging with gdb", but didn't find some. If you could point out where they are, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
print memcpy (the_array_you_want_to_modify, {newvalue1, newvalue2, ..., newvalueN}, N * sizeof(the_array_you_want_to_modify[0]))
```

may be what you're looking for?