# Is there a REPL for C programming?

Tags: c, read-eval-print-loop

I am on osx. I  found this 
http://neugierig.org/software/c-repl/
but the links on that page for code seem to be broken.

Comment: Just adding a link to this post with some c-repl examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459678/where-can-i-find-c-repl-documentation/6902522#6902522

Comment: See also [Is there an interpreter for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c)

Comment: ClangRepl looks good: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangRepl.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Seems like the code of *c-repl* can now be found at a [Github repository](https://github.com/martine/c-repl). It seems to be a dead project, though (last commit was 3 years ago), so I'd suggest looking into alternatives as well:

- CINT [Archived old official page from web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504034257/http://root.cern.ch/cint) or ["Masaharu Goto" CINT page](http://www.hanno.jp/gotom/Cint.html)
- ccons [Github](https://github.com/asvitkine/ccons) or [code.google](http://code.google.com/p/ccons/)
- [Cling](https://root.cern/cling/), successor of CINT, but only supports C++ (which might or might not be a problem, depending on what features you need)

Comment: which one of them do you think is suitable to use

Answer (score 37):

Just found the [IGCC](http://www.artificialworlds.net/wiki/IGCC/IGCC) (Interactive GCC) REPL.  I like it.

Example:

```
./igcc

g++> int a = 1, b = 2;
g++> printf("%d\n", a + b);
3
g++>
```

And it gives you compile errors like this:

```
g++> c = 3;
[Compile error - type .e to see it.]
g++> .e
<stdin>:14:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'c'
c = 3;
^
```

(SF download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/igcc/files/)

Comment: There's an updated version (Python 3) at https://github.com/alexandru-dinu/igcc

Answer (score 30):

[gdb](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/) makes a pretty good REPL.  You can't define new functions there, but you can evaluate expressions (including those with side effects).

Comment: An example of how to use gdb as a reply would be nice.

Comment: An example of how to use gdb: 1) `gdb /bin/ls` 2) `print "Hello world"[0]`   Of course it gets more involved than that... but even that simple example illustrates a common C idiom in a repl

Comment: On Mac OS with gdb 6.3.50, the example above give: "evaluation of this expression requires the target program to be active"

Comment: @snow aha - right you are, gdb won't actually work as a repl unless it is attached to some actually running process.  There is more than one way to achieve this.  Usually breaking on "main" works on Linux, but system programs like "ls" often don't have this.  The following worked on Centos5:  1) gdb /bin/ls 2) break readdir 3) run 4) print "hello world"

Comment: gdb seems a bit finicky sometimes... for instance: `(gdb) print printf("test\n");` `No symbol "printf" in current context.`  which is funny, because I just stepped over a call to printf!

Comment: This answer fails to meet what I would consider minimum qualifications for an answer: `(gdb) int a = 5;
Ambiguous command "int a = 5;": internals, interpreter-exec, interrupt.
(gdb) `