# Open the terminal and execute commands via C programming

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-10.04

Does someone know how to open the terminal and execute several commands using a C program ?

I have a program in C and another sets of commands executed by the terminal. I need to combine them into one program in C.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for a C interpreter. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226156/linux-c-shell-like-environment-for-individual-execution-of-c-commands-c-i

Comment: You can execute terminal commands via the `system` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check "man xterm", parameter -e. Then, in C, you can:

system("xterm -e ls")

Answer (score 3):

Your question may be somewhat misleading.

Because you want to run all the terminal commands in the c-code, perhaps you actually have only textual input / output with these commands.  If so, you probably do not need the terminal.

---

I use popen when the output of the (terminal) program is a text stream.  It is probably the easiest to use. As an example:

```
 ...
 const char* cmndStr = "ls -lsa";
 FILE* pipe = popen(cmndStr, "r");
 ...
```

The popen instruction executes the command in the cmndStr, and any text written to the commands (ls -lsa) standard output, is redirected into the pipe, which is then available for your C program to read in.

popen opens a separate process (but without a terminal to work in, just the pipe)

'Fork' is another way to launch a separate process, with some control over the launched processes' std i/o, but again, I think not a terminal.

---

On the other hand, if your output is not a simple text stream, maybe you can get by with a output-only dedicated terminal screen to accommodate special output activity.  For instance, when I work with ncurses:

I manually open a terminal in the conventional way, and in the terminal

- issue the command "tty" to find out the device name, and
- issue a "cd" to set the focus to the working dir.

  dmoen@C5:~$ tty

  /dev/pts/1

  dmoen@C5:~$ cd work

  dmoen@C5:~/work$

Then I start my program (in a different tty), and let the program know which device I want it to use for the special output (i.e. /dev/pts/1 ) ... I typically use command line parameters to tell my program which pts or extra terminals I want it to use, but environment variables, pipes, in/out redirection, and other choices exist.

I have not tried (lately) to launch a terminal (as suggested by smrt28), except in shell.  I believe this will work, but I do not see how the output from the terminal command (ls in the example) would be delivered back to your program.  popen trivially delivers a text stream.

A long time ago, I used a device called 'pty' which works like a terminal, but I don't remember how to connect it usefully.

---

There is a set of 'exec' commands ... see man exec.  To connect them back to your program, you will probably work with files, or perhaps redirecting i/o.  Too many choices to list here.

---

And also, maybe you can connect these commands with your c program using shell pipes.

Comment: o.k, Ill be more specific- im using gstreamer (server and client) and I run the gstreamer commands (pipeline) with the terminal. I also have C program ( server and client) co the client sends to the server some data with TCP. now I need co combine those programs into one C program and run the pipeline (both the client and server) with the C program.

Comment: example of the pipeline command (server side): gst-launch videotestsrc ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000